# How to get the timer job name from timer job id in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, powershell, timer-jobs

how to get the timer job name from a given timerjob id in sharepoint 2010 server farm.
ex: i have a timer job id

```
Get-SPTimerJob | Where {$_.id -eq "xxxxxxxx3"} | ft id,name
```

it displaying empty results, what is the proper way to get the name of timer job name or from central administration is any way

Comment: id means GUID? or something else

Comment: if you providve the proper guid then you will get it. run get-sptimerjob -identity "" and see if it return anything

Comment: Actually, your code is OK. As @WaqasSarwarMCSE said, it seems to be an issue with your `"xxxxxxxx3"` literal. PS: please consider adding `powershell` tag to your question

Comment: i just given some example id here xxxxx

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be

```
$id = [GUID]("xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx3")  // whatever your id is as string
Get-SPTimerJob -Identity $id | select Name, DisplayName
```